# ocaml object with external function as method

Tags: object, ocaml, external

Sometimes one wants to write bindings for some C code using ocaml modules as interface or optimize some method of an object in C. But one can't define the external function before the object because it needs the type of the object and one can't define the object because it needs to call the external function.

One solution is to use recursive modules but that easily tripples the source size and becomes awfully unreadable. The external functions also enter the modules namespace and need to be hidden again. So what is a shorter, more readable solution?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use first class modules to define an external function directly inside an objec. First one needs an module type to be used by the first class module. This is generic and can be used for any kind of external function over and over:

```
module type External = sig
    type e
    val stub : e
end
```

after that once can declare external functions like this:

```
class c =
  let ext = (module struct
    type e = c -> unit
    external stub : c -> unit = "stub"
  end : External with type e = c -> unit)
  in
object(self:'self)
  method as_c = (self :> c)
  method foo =
    let module E = (val ext)
    in
    E.stub self#as_c
end
```

or even more local within the method itself as:

```
class c = object(self:'self)
  method as_c = (self :> c)
  method foo =
    let module E = (val (module struct
      type t = c -> unit
      external stub : c -> unit = "stub"
    end) : External with type t = c -> unit)
    in
    E.stub self#as_c
end
```

Note: the as_c method avoids the (open) self type getting closed or escaping its scope.